# Dynamically creating expression in ArcMap model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, feature-class, expression

I am trying to build a model that iterates through feature classes in a `.gdb` and uses the name of `feature class` (they are named by state abbreviations) to make a new layer from a second `feature class` based on that name.
[image]

The second feature class, `osm_bing_diff_uniqueid` has a field called `st_abbr` that identifies a feature by state abbreviation. What I want to do is parse the `Name` output of the first feature class into the expression for the `Make Feature Layer` of the second feature class. For example, if the Name = `AL_Bldg_FP_Parcels`, I to make a feature class of all the features in `osm_bing_diff_uniqueid` where the `st_abbr` field value is `AL`. I am a little confused as to how to use the Name as an input and parse it into the expression.

Any suggestions?
[image: Fe]

Comment: Are you iterating through the features in a single feature class, or through a number of feature classes in the .gdb? The first sentence isn't clear.

Comment: Through feature classes in a .gdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Calculate Value (from model only tools)](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/calculate-value.htm) to get this value. If you put this python expression in Expression argument, `%Name%[:2]`, it should give the first two letters of the `Name` in-line variable in a new variable, `output_value` by default. Then you can introduce this into your query builder as in-line variable, for example, `"st_abbrv" = '%output_value%'`.

**UPDATE**

You should introduce Calculate Value both preconditioned to the Name iterator output and as a precondition to the Make Feature Layer.

Comment: Do I need to use code block somehow in connecting `Name` as an input to `Calculate Value`? When I add "Name%[:2] " (or anything other than just `Name`), the connection arrow disappears. Should I just use `Name` as a precondition to running Calculate Value? Everytime I iterate through the `.gdb`, I want it to get a new `Name` and calculate a new `output_value` to input in my `Make Feature Layer` process.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that detail, you should introduce `Calculate Value` both preconditioned to the `Name` iterator output and as a precondition to the Make Feature Layer.